# What is the norm of $L(f)=f(1)-f(0)$, $f\in C^0([0,1],\mathbb{R},\|\cdot\|_{\infty})$?

Tags: functional-analysis, banach-spaces

Find the norm of $L(f)=f(1)-f(0)$, $f\in C^0([0,1],\mathbb{R},\|\cdot\|_{\infty})$.

$$\left \| L(f) \right \|_{\mathbb{R}}\leq \left \| f(1)-f(0) \right \|_{\mathbb{R}}\leq 2\left \| f \right \|_{\infty}$$
I take $g(x)=x$, $g(1)-g(0)=1-0=1$, and $\left \| g \right \|_{\infty}=1$. So
$$\|g\|=\|L(g)\|_{\mathbb{R}}=\|g\|_{\infty}=1.$$
I have 2 differents value for the norm of $L$. Any advice please, Thank you.

Comment: Don’t include part of the body of the question in the title!

Comment: You should explicitly define your norm. I'm assuming you're using $\|\cdot\|=\max|L(f)|/\| f\|_\infty$. Then the norm for $L$ is $2$ which is attaned by $2x-1$.

Comment: Yes, How do you find that function ? Thank you.

Comment: You just need to achieve a function that is symmetric with f(0) and f(1) both being being the same extreme value, one positive, one negative.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The norm of $L$ is the maximum distance between $f(0)$ and $f(1)$ for $f\in C([0,1])$ such that $\left \|f\right \|_{\infty}=1.$ It is equal to $2$ and attained e.g. if $f(0)=-1$ and $f(1)=1.$